# Как на чистом JS обвернуть каждые N элементов с одинаковым классом

Tags: javascript

Есть ряд блоков например:

```
<div class="item">
Item 1
</div>
<div class="item">
Item 2
</div>
<div class="item">
Item 3
</div>
<div class="item">
Item 4
</div>
<div class="item">
Item 5
</div>
```

Нужно на чистом JS добавить обвертку через каждые N блоков например через каждые три штуки. Открывающий тэг первой обвертки и закрывающий тэг последней можно дописать прямо в код, но все промежуточные тэги обверток нужно добавлять именно на Javascript'e, поскольку для разных экранов будет разное N (html генерируется на РНР, а РНР не понимает размеры экранов).

Попробовал решить задачу вот так:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="item">
Item 1
</div>
<div class="item">
Item 2
</div>
<div class="item">
Item 3
</div>
<div class="item">
Item 4
</div>
<div class="item">
Item 5
</div>
</div><!--wrap-->
<script>
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var number = i*1+1*1;
    if(number % 3 === 0) {
        items[i].outerHTML = items[i].outerHTML+"</div><!--wrap-->\n<div class=\"wrap\">";
    }
}
</script>
```

Но в инструментах разработчика в Хроме вижу что после третьего блока просто получаю пустую обвертку:

```
...
<div class="item">
Item 3
</div>
<!--wrap-->
<div class="wrap"></div>
<div class="item">
Item 4
</div>
...
```

Хотя должно быть:

```
...
<div class="item">
Item 3
</div>
</div><!--wrap-->
<div class="wrap">
<div class="item">
Item 4
</div>
...
```

В общем нужен аналог

```
var items = $('.item');
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i += 3) {
    items.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll('<div class="wrap"></div>');
}
```

только на чистом JS

Comment: врапиться должен каждый третий элемент или элементы должны врапиться блоками по 3?

Comment: Каждые три блока т.е. блоками по три

Comment: Псевдокласс [`nth-child`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child) Вам в помощь.

Comment: @Other, и как он тут поможет?

Comment: @Grundy, ну автор хочет вставить между каждыми N код - этот псевдокласс поможет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте в таком духе.

При нахождении каждого третьего элемента создавать новый элемент wrap и переносить элементы с текущей позиции в качестве дочерних для созданного wrap элемента.

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
var wrap;
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i ++) {
  if (i%3 === 0)
  {
  wrap = document.createElement('div');
  wrap.className = "wrap";
  document.body.appendChild(wrap);
  }
  wrap.appendChild(items[i]);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  Item 1
</div>
<div class="item">
  Item 2
</div>
<div class="item">
  Item 3
</div>
<div class="item">
  Item 4
</div>
<div class="item">
  Item 5
</div>
```

Comment: добавь описание что у тебя в коде происходит

Comment: @Grundy, не нужно, я понимаю суть, сам думал об этом решении...

Comment: @stckvrw, Нужно в любом случае, так как ответ видишь не только ты.

Comment: бтв интересно можно ли хвостом за элементами перенести блоки комментариев.

Comment: @yolosora, Это вопрос?

Comment: @Grundy вопрос!

Comment: @yolosora, да, комментарии тоже можно переносить

Answer (score 1):

```js
/* получаем контейнер */
var container = document.getElementById("container1");

/* получаем item-ы у контейнера */
var allElements = Array.from(container.getElementsByClassName("item"));

var wrapSize = 3;

for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i += wrapSize) {

  /* создаём врап */
  var wrap = document.createElement("div");
  wrap.classList.add("wrap");

  /* наполняем нужным количеством элементов */
  for (var j = 0; j < wrapSize; j++) {
    if (i + j < allElements.length) {
      wrap.appendChild(allElements[i + j]);
    }
  }
  
  /* добавляем в контейнер */
  container.appendChild(wrap);
}
```

```css
.wrap {
 background-color: silver;
 margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
  <div class="item">
    Item 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 3
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 4
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 5
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 6
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 7
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 8
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: цикл с вызовом remove() - не нужен. добавь описание что у тебя в коде происходит

Comment: @Grundy да, я уже поправил

Comment: Очищать контейнер тоже не надо

Comment: @Grundy ага, тоже поправил

Comment: @Grundy они сами удаляются при append-е.

Comment: На самом деле они не удаляются. Они **перемещаются**

Comment: @Grundy да.....